# debugger for node not working

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js

This is probably something really simple but scouring the web for a nodeJS replacement for ruby's `binding.pry`

I have the following `testDebugger.js`:

```
var x = 10;
debugger;
var y = 5;
```

Then I run the following in the terminal:

```
$ node debug testDebugger.js
```

I type in x and get `ReferenceError: x is not defined`

Heres the entire sequence:

```
$ node debug app.js
< Debugger listening on port 5858
debug> . ok
break in app.js:1
> 1 var x = 10;
  2 debugger;
  3 var y = 5;
debug> x
repl:1
x
^
ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

any ideas? Really love `binding.pry` in my rails apps and i hate being relegated to millions of `console.log()`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to inspect variables You could switch into `repl` mode.

Also note that debugger has stopped at the first line, so `x` is not declared yet.

```
debug> cont
debug> repl
> x
10
```

Comment: [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) may be more convenient for you.